# gnuplot heatmap: data appears "slanted"

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I need some help

I have huge file that contains 256 frequencies with their amplitudes every 3 seconds, meaning for each specific time (i.e. 18:04:01), there is 256 lines. The first column is the time:  YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS, the second columns is the frequency, and the third column is the amplitude value. Each column is separated with a space

```
2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.823047180175781250e+02 -4.882478713989257812e+01
*<256 lines>*
2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.6047180175781250e+02 -4.882478713989257812e+01
2022-02-27-18:39:54 1.823047180175781250e+02 -4.533270263671875000e+01
*<256 lines>*
2022-02-27-18:39:54 1.6047180175781250e+02 -4.882478713989257812e+01
```

Here is the gnuplot code that I am using to plot this:

```
clear
reset
reset session
set timestamp "Generated:  %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" top font 'Arial,16'
set datafile separator " "
set datafile missing "nan"
set term pngcairo
set terminal png size 1500,800
set title "$systemName \n \nSpectrum\n Most recently appended:  $file_most_current_pwr" font 'Consolas,19' noenhanced
set cblabel "Amplitude dB" offset 3 font 'Consolas, 15'
set cbtics scale 0 font 'Arial,16'
#set cbrange [:-40]
set palette rgbformulae 22,13,-31
unset key
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M:%S"
set ylabel 'MHz' font 'Arial,19' offset 0,2
set xlabel 'Time' font 'Arial,19' 
set output "/var/www/html/and_power_plot.png"
plot "/var/www/html/Data_Archive/current_master_PWR_data.txt" using 1:2:3 with image
```

However, I am getting a heatmap that looks "slanted". In addition, I received this error when I append further data to the file:

```
Visible pixel grid has a scan line longer than previous scan lines
```

Here is the graph:

[Slanted GNUplot heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QePyi.png)

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out that the data has to have a blank line between each line, for example, instead of:

```
2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.82000000000000e+02 -4.882478713989257812e+01
2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.70000000000000e+02 -3.8567889999398992e+01
2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.62300000000050e+02 -4.882478711568033333812e+01
```

needs to be like this:

```
2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.82000000000000e+02 -4.882478713989257812e+01

2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.70000000000000e+02 -3.8567889999398992e+01

2022-02-27-18:39:57 1.62300000000050e+02 -4.882478711568033333812e+01
```